# Which one is true, "We could enjoy French poetry without mastering French" or, "we don't need to enjoy French poetry"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/a7tfyzeZJCc?t=76)

> you can't enjoy
>   French poetry until you've learned a lot
>   of French vocabulary and grammar
>   including all its quirks and
>   irregularities

this part sounds reasonable - you have to understand sth and then you could enjoy/appreciate that thing (like French poetry).

> quite understandably some
>   people find this off-putting my French
>   is still terrible for example ...

this part gets wired, which conflicts with the first part, I cannot get the point what the lecturer is actually expressing.

is it that we could enjoy French poetry without mastering French? or, I don't need to enjoy French poetry?

Comment: Hey, that guy writing up mathematical formulae in mirror-writing is so impressive...

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, that's why I am interested in his metaphors in such a carefully prepared video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is saying "You can enjoy French poetry, but first you must learn a lot of vocabulary and grammar".

He is using this as an analogy for "You can enjoy creating artificial intelligence, but first you must learn a lot of multivariable calculus."

The idea is that "poetry" or "AI" is something that lots of people want to do, but they are put off by "grammar" or "calculus".  He notes that he can't enjoy French poetry because "his French [language skill] is terrible". He is an example of someone who is put off by the grammar. It is a casual remark, aiming to empathise with the student.  *I know this is difficult and even boring for you. I feel the same about grammar, but trust me when I tell you that, if you learn this boring stuff you will be able to appreciate the* poetry *of machine learning much better.*